# DBeaver export SQL file as INSERT statements with aliased columns names

Tags: sql, postgresql, export, resultset, dbeaver

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    id as address_uuid,
    parent_addresses_id as parent_address_uuid,
    CONCAT_WS(', ',
    address_street1,
    address_street2,
    parsed_city,
    parsed_state,
    parsed_postal) as address,
    parcel_master_units as units,
    fiber_type as tenancy_type,
    created_date as created_at,
    modified_date as updated_at
FROM 
    addresses
WHERE 
    parsed_city = 'Minneapolis'
AND 
    deleted != 1
```

Anyone know how I can export it as a SQL file of INSERT Statements with the columns matching my aliases like so:

```
INSERT INTO addresses (address_uuid,parent_address_uuid,address,units,tenancy_type,created_at,updated_at) VALUES (...)
```

Rather than what it is currently exporting:

```
INSERT INTO addresses (id,parent_addresses_id,address,parcel_master_units,fiber_type,created_date,modified_date) VALUES (...)
```

Or another GUI that can handle this? I'm attempting to migrate a lot of address data, which would be easy if I could get the INSERT Statements to have the correct column names for the new table.

Comment: Either remove the alias or change it to the desired value as your GUI is exporting the value from the query.  So for example instead of "id as address_uuid," just make it "id".

Comment: I need the INSERT statement's column names to match the aliases though.

Comment: Change the ALIAS on the select. The exported insert statement will then contain that name.

Comment: Change it to what? I'm exporting from the above query, which has the aliased columns. The only one that actually retains the alias in the INSERT statements is the CONCAT_WS () as address column. The others revert to their original column names.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this GUI based approach in DBeaver.

Right click table-> Export Data. This will open up Data Transfer Wizard. Choose Database from the options. Check the options and if you are good then hit "Next". This will give you option to select Target Container (Schema). Select your desired Target.

Next, beside Source, you should see blank as Target. Click "Create New" (bottom left) to create new table. Click the drop down arrow ( > ) besides source table name and this should bring the list of columns. Then you are good to select columns and rename them as per the requirements. Moreover, if you select columns' mapping, you will find more options to control data types.

Hope this helps with your question.

Answer (score 0):

This hacky solution worked:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(id) as address_uuid,
    CONCAT(parent_addresses_id) as parent_address_uuid,
    CONCAT_WS(', ',
    address_street1,
    address_street2,
    parsed_city,
    parsed_state,
    parsed_postal) as address,
    CONCAT(parcel_master_units) as units,
    CONCAT(fiber_type) as tenancy_type,
    CONCAT(created_date) as created_at,
    CONCAT(modified_date) as updated_at
FROM 
    addresses
WHERE 
    parsed_city = 'Minneapolis'
AND deleted != 1
```

Not sure why the alias were not being applied to the exported INSERT statements, so if anyone knows the trick to solving that, I'd love to know!

Answer (score -1):

Change the current query:

```
SELECT
    id as address_uuid,
    parent_addresses_id as parent_address_uuid,
    CONCAT_WS(', ',
    address_street1,
    address_street2,
    parsed_city,
    parsed_state,
    parsed_postal) as address,
    parcel_master_units as units,
    fiber_type as tenancy_type,
    created_date as created_at,
    modified_date as updated_at ...
```

To contain the desirded column names, since you say "revert to original name" just remove the alias:

```
SELECT
    id,
    parent_addresses_id,
    CONCAT_WS(', ',
    address_street1,
    address_street2,
    parsed_city,
    parsed_state,
    parsed_postal) as address,
    parcel_master_units, 
    fiber_type,
    created_date,
    modified_date  ...
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding. They are already reverting to the original column name, despite the aliases. I want them aliased. DBeaver isn't maintaining the aliases on export.

Comment: Yes I was misunderstanding; sorry.  I just downloaded DBeaveer 6.1.2 and I think it can do what you want interactively, don't know about as a script. In the sql editor window execute your SQL. Then in the results wondow select the entrie grid and right click. There is an Export option there that seems to retain the alias from the query. Again don't know if this is available as a script/macro. Good Luck.